# Place Title Inside using Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'am totally clueless, but have managed to get Fancybox v2.1.0 working by using the many great answers found here. Now, I would like to change the title position to the "inside" - I see various code for this, such as:

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
helpers : {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    }
}
```

});

But I have no idea where to put that - do I edit the jquery.fancybox.js file? If so, where? I see on line 182 where simply the title type can be changed, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

After nailing this down, I'd like to change the open/close to "elastic", so any help there would be appreciated as well. Don't have a sample page online - but it's the basic page of thumbnails, each clicked to open a larger single image.

Many thanks in advance - sorry to be such a newbie on this - previously used Lightbox, but Fancybox seems to fit better for what I need.

**EDIT** (moved code from comments)
here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/... 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".fancybox").fancybox(); 
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mess with original js file, you just need to load fancybox in your html document ([see what to include here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions))

Then, within the `<head>` section of your html document, include this script (after you loaded jQuery and fancybox js files as in the instructions above)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    helpers     : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
  });​
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tried that, only to get no change to the default Fancybox that I have working. With the script you gave placed below it, and within the Head tags, here is what I have:  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
</script>

Comment: @user1672677 : replace the part of fancybox as in my example within the `<head>` tag.

Comment: @user1672677 : also make sure you are loading the fancybox js file (I don't see it in your code)... it should look like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>`

Comment: Really appreciate your help. The character limit likely has me making things confusing, and I cannot seem to get the code view to work. I do have Fancybox working, it calls up the linked larger image, and I can enter a title. Just not able to modify it as originally stated. The code I have in between head tags is:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/…; <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $(".fancybox").fancybox(); }); </script>

Comment: When I place the code you gave below that, (still within head tags) nothing changes. No elastic, no title inside. If I try to wrap the code you gave within the ready(function) code that calls fancybox, it negates the whole thing back to where the larger image opens in a new window. Sorry, I'm so lost.

Comment: @user1672677: share a link to your page and I will tell you exactly what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks. This is a temp directory, and incomplete page created just for viewing. Not all thumbnails are uploaded, and only the first four have been linked to the Fancybox JS:
http://www.hank3.com/in_the_camouflage/damnband.html

Comment: you just need a single script so remove `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`. Also you have a js error originated from am unrecognized character in line 34... most likely when you copied/pasted the code from here. Maje sure that your text editor is using UTF-8 without BOM character encoding.

Comment: Thanks so much. I believe I've got it figured out, if you could look once more just for quality control I'd much appreciate it. (I had to refresh to see the changes). Thanks for you patience and knowledgeable help.
http://www.hank3.com/in_the_camouflage/damnband.html