# Fancybox 2.1.5 - putting title inside the photo window

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, fancybox, title

I'm trying to put the title text within the box containing photos on this page: http://annekathleen.com/pages/wholesale-lookbook

I've Googled and tried a few different methods, but nothing's worked so far. I am a javascript newbie.

I changed the type position to inside, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: None of your fancybox v2.1.5 js and css files are loading. They all return a 404 error (file not found) ... you need to verify your paths. You see fancybox working because there is an [old version](view-source:http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/3195/t/3/assets/jquery.fancybox.js?2250) installed (v1.3.1 which loading). Additionally you are loading 2 different versions of jQuery and that will make your site prone to additional js errors.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how to test that, though had considered it. And I just realized why they weren't loading since the domain is hosted w/ shopify, and I uploaded to my godaddy server... thank you for pointing it out! Obviously I was having a brain-freeze moment

Comment: Once you have it ready, check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 2 for samples how to put the title inside (or check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12435300/1055987 for a direct code sample). If I was you, I would disregard @jungerislaender answer since you shouldn't mess with the original js or css files but set the API options in your own custom initialization script.

Answer (score -1):

You have some possibilities:

1. You add some css:

   ## fancybox-title {

   ```
    top: 0 !IMPORTANT;
   ```

   }
2. You use the available js option for fancybox. Written down here:
   http://fancybox.net/api: Perhaps titlePosition: top; works.
3. You use the non minified js version: jquery.fancybox.js
   and change the source code (not tested):

Line 1871

```
F.helpers.title = {
    defaults : {
        type     : 'float', // 'float', 'inside', 'outside' or 'over',
        position : 'bottom' // 'top' or 'bottom'
    },
```

I recomment 1.

Comment: Thanks! Once I get it linking correctly I'll give that a try!